# Django Redirect to current page

Tags: django, redirect

I am having troubles with the redirect to the same page user was on after logging in, no matter how hard I tried and read all the questions here. I think it is high time I showed folks out here my code so if you can point out mistake(s). Thanks.

My login url (in base.html template):
This is present on every page. Changes to logout once the user is logged in. I read that I have to pass a param for example 'next' like this:

```
 <a href="/login/?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

but,

### **The `{{request.path}}` is always empty. **

login view:

```
def mylogin(request):
    """login view"""
    try:
        redirect_to = request.GET.get('next', '/')
    except ValueError:
        redirect_to = "/"

errors = ''
t = loader.get_template('login.html')


# check for POST data
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            c = Context({
                'errors':'disabled',
            })
            return HttpResponse("disabled")
    else:
        c = Context({
            'errors':'incorrect',
        })
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
else:
    c = Context({
        'errors':None,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

---

The login form, in login.html template

```
 <form method="post" action="?next={{ redirect_to }}" >
       <p><label for="username">Username</p>
       <p></label><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" /></p>
       <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
       <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" /></p>
       <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not passing `request` to the template context, so naturally it's empty. The easiest way to get it in there is to use a RequestContext, which uses the built-in context processors to add variables to the context.

The usual way to do this is to use `render_to_response` with the extra parameter `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`. For some reason, you're rendering all your templates the long way, so you'll need to create that requestcontext yourself.

You'll also need to add `django.core.context_processors.request` to the `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` tuple ins settings.py.

Comment: oh. why is `render_to_response` shorter than `HttpResponse` ?

Comment: It's not. It's shorter than three separate calls to `get_template`, `t.render`, and `HttpResponse`, which is what it does.